# Spitting out an information when an item is selected on a drop down menu?

Tags: html

I was wondering if its possible to use something such as JavaScript to spit out a text under a drop down menu after a user selects one of the items listed on the drop down?

**For example:**
A user clicks on a drop down menu and select Choice B. Under the menu, it will say anything like "You have selected Choice B" or "Choice B cost: $0.00"

Is this possible?

My current code is:

```
<form>
<p align="center"><b>Select a Payment:</b>
<select id="setit" style="color: #000" size="1" name="test">
<option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="">1 Month: $4.99</option>
    <option value="">3 Months: $14.99</option>
     <option value="">6 Months: $29.99</option></select>
<br />
<br />
     <input type="button" value="Add to Cart"
onclick="window.open(setit.options[setit.selectedIndex].value)">
</p></form>
```

Can anybody help me? I am currently lost and is a noob at coding lol. I searched around and saw people posting a JavaScript using Variables, but every time I inset the coding, nothing appears...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind jQuery or should it be straight javascript? (The former being much simpler piece of code).

Comment: I would like javascript as of right now so I can learn more about it. I never messed with jQuery so I might be confused about it. Sorry

Comment: How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WaWEZ/1/ (using the `data-*` attributes to hold the values, otherwise you're going to need to either parse out the name from the price or use the `value` attribute to store both)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on `DOM` manipulation with JavaScript. It is very possible, and I suggest you have a look at the JavaScript Tutorial from [w3schools.org](http://www.w3schools.org). It is very comprehensive, and when your ready, you should download jQuery and use that: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.org).

Good Luck
-Brian

Comment: I will definately look into this and learn more. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form> 
<p align="center"><b>Select a Payment:</b> 
<select id="setit" style="color: #000" size="1" name="test" onchange="displayValue();"> 
   <option value="">Select one</option>     
   <option value="">1 Month: $4.99</option>    
   <option value="">3 Months: $14.99</option>      
   <option value="">6 Months: $29.99</option>
</select> 
<br /> <br />
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="window.open(setit.options[setit.selectedIndex].value)"> </p></form>
<div id="displayValue">here</div>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
function displayValue()
{

var e = document.getElementById("setit");    
var strSel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;     
document.getElementById("displayValue").innerHTML = strSel; 
}
-->
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do so! However, on the <"option value=""> section, Im using that to input a URL so when the user clicks on one of the listed items, it goes straight to that URL when clicking on the "Add to Cart" button. However, when I input the Value="", the DisplayValue spits out the URL instead of what I wanted. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<p align="center"><b>Select a Payment:</b>
<select id="setit" onchange="javascript:showRelatedValue(this.value)">
<option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="">1 Month: $4.99</option>
    <option value="">3 Months: $14.99</option>
    <option value="">6 Months: $29.99</option></select>
<br />
<br />
     <input type="button" value="Add to Cart"
onclick="window.open(setit.options[setit.selectedIndex].value)">
</p>
</form>

<script>
     function showRelatedValue(String value)
     {
         if(value==1 Month: $4.99)
         alert("you have selected choice A");
         if(value==3 Months: $14.99)
         alert("you have selected choice B");
         if(value==6 Months: $29.99)
         alert("you have selected choice C");
     }
</script>
```

well i have compared just by if conditions but u should compared with a given array or in best scenario , use ajax calls to bring related response from a server.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<form> 
<p align="center"><b>Select a Payment:</b> 
<select id="setit" style="color: #000" size="1" name="test" > 
   <option value="http://www.msnbc.com">Select one</option>     
   <option value="http://www.microsoft.com">1 Month: $4.99</option>    
   <option value="http://google.com">3 Months: $14.99</option>      
   <option value="http://msn.com">6 Months: $29.99</option>
</select> 
<br /> <br />
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="showLink()"> </p></form>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
function showLink()
{

var e = document.getElementById("setit");    
var strSel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;   
window.open(strSel);
}
-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```